# How to publish an Office 365 MS Outlook Addin

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office365api, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

I have published v1 of my Office 365 Outlook AddIn a few months ago via seller dashboard.

Now, I need to publish an update. The old version is hosted on a server and placed in some directory:

/AddInV1/

New Addin I have placed like this -
/AddInV2/

So, now while EDIT in Seller dashboard - Do I need to replace code in same folder or I just need to refer the manifest from 2nd folder?

The goal is that once second is published - must show as an UPDATE available to the existing Users.

Thanks in advance,
Kanak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your update doesn’t require any manifest changes then you can just update the code in your site at the current url. You only need to resubmit if you need to update your manifest, in which case you submit a new manifest and it can point wherever you want.

Comment: Thank for the answer.  There are lots of changes in my manifest. Also I ned to update the version number of my addin.